# Sum values across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm having trouble trying to sum a field GROUPED BY a common user ID from TWO DIFFERENT tables.

To give you a little more info... I am trying to track player performances by date (i.e.: most points scored on ALL Nov. 14's). The database is split, one table for regular season games and one table for playoffs. So, for example, a player may have played a regular season game on May 3, 2001....but a playoff game on May 3, 2005.

So, I'm trying to build a view with the sums of every player on all dates.

What I have for a single table:

```
SELECT PlayerId,sum(Points) as TOT_PTS 
FROM RS_games 
WHERE DAY(Date)=$cur_day 
  AND MONTH(Date)=$cur_month 
GROUP BY PlayerId
```

...but I can't figure how I could sum the values of each player across two tables without creating a third view as a "stepping stone".
Any ideas?

Comment: And you want to group by day and month?

Comment: correct - final table should have every player's point total on May, 3, for example

Comment: With sub-queries you can do the GROUP BY and SUM() on each table one a at a time, then JOIN the result into your main table (or just two tables into each other if you don't need main table data).

Comment: @dsol828. I undeleted my answer with a approach that i think works for you. See if it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results by (DAY-MONTH) you can do:

```
SELECT playerID, 
       CONCAT (DAY(DATE), '-', MONTH(DATE)) AS DAY_MONTH, 
       SUM(points) AS Total_Points
FROM (
  SELECT playerID, DATE, points
  FROM rs_games  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT playerID, DATE, points
  FROM po_games
  ) a
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88305/7)</kbd>

This way, you would end up with a result with every playerId,dd-mm, and the sum of points that were scored in that specific day across the years.

Comment: Couldn't this cause double-counting if more than one game were played on a single day by the same player in both tables?  (I guess that'd be 4 games, so perhaps we're safe, but in a general solution this would be a problem)

Comment: Looking at the query again, this can have multiple holes, yes. I'm going to delete it for now.

Comment: How exactly would this produce an error? Just want to make sure.

Comment: @dsol828. It isn't this version. It's the first i posted. I then edited it and wrote this one. :)

Comment: @FilipeSilva Ya, the sub-query with UNION is a lot cleaner.

Comment: @ebyrob. I think so to. To get this with JOINs was my first thought, but i think the union solves the problem without leaving much holes.

Comment: @FilipeSilva Let me know if you see a problem in my solution, I don't.  But, yours is simpler and far more flexible to changing demands.

Answer (score 0):

Just to lay out what I was saying:

```
select
  ALL_players.PlayerID as PlayerID
  COALESCE(reg.Points, 0) + COALESCE(po.Points, 0) as Points
from
ALL_players
left join
(select PlayerID, DATE(Date) as Date, sum(Points) as Points 
 from RS_games
 WHERE DAY(Date)=$cur_day AND MONTH(Date)=$cur_month
 group by PlayerID) as reg
on reg.PlayerID = ALL_players.PlayerID
left join
(select PlayerID, DATE(Date) as Date, sum(Points) as Points 
 from PO_games group by DATE(Date), PlayerID
 WHERE DAY(Date)=$cur_day AND MONTH(Date)=$cur_month
 group by PlayerID) as po
on po.PlayerID = ALL_players.PlayerID
```

**EDIT:** Looking again at requirements this will need either a full outer join or some adjustment...  adjusting (should be working now)

Comment: I'd love to try your solution, but keep getting the following error. I can't find the syntax error.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COALESCE(reg.Points, 0) + COALESCE(po.Points, 0) as Points
from
ALL_players
left' at line 3

Comment: scratch that missing comma after PlayerID. My mysql client doesn't allow subqueries, however....hmmm